# how can i convert a particular table records in a Database and convert them into markdown and .rst files in python

Tags: python, database, markdown, restructuredtext

I have a DB dump, I want to convert a particular table (table name: blogentry) records in that DB to be converted into markdown and .rst files. And want to create a static site with them? Is it possible help me out!

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

Convert your dump to a CSV file.

For reStructuredText, use the [`csv-table` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#csv-table) in your .rst files.

Use [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/) to render the .rst files to HTML.

If you get stuck, then ask a new question with more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) module that allow to generate html document from *.rst.

**Installation:**

```
pip install sphinx
```

Then You have to write a little module generating rst from database.

**Example:** write while generating your rst from db

```
+---------+---------+-----------+
| Field1  |  Field2 |  Field3   |
+---------+---------+-----------+
```